# How could I solve the error in the following code in tab navigation?

Tags: java, android

I'm unable to find out the error in the below code in tab navigation.

> How could I solve this in the below code?

I'm finding quite difficult in finding out the error. Kindly please help me to get solved in the below error in the below mentioned code..

The errors occurred in,

```
    PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),fragments);
            final ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
            pager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

and also in the below lines

```
            ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

                    pager.getCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

                }
```

And the full code is

```
        import android.app.Fragment;
        import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
        import android.support.v4.view.*;
        import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
        import android.os.Bundle;
        import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
        import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
        import android.widget.TableLayout;
        //import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;

        import java.util.List;
        import java.util.Vector;

        public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<>();
                fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, FragmentOne.class.getName()));
                fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, FragmentTwo.class.getName()));

             PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),fragments);
                final ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
                pager.setAdapter(adapter);

                final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
                actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

                ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

                        pager.getCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

                    }
                };

                actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("page 1").setTabListener(tabListener));
                actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("page 2").setTabListener(tabListener));

                pager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                        actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                    }
                });
            }
        }


import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by seyali-01 on 14/11/16.
 */

public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private List<Fragment> fragments;

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
        super(fm);
        this.fragments = fragments;
    }



    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {

        return fragments.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragments.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: what is that error?

Comment: The word "error" appears 11 times (!) in your post, but yet a proper error message or problem description cannot be found. Please refine your question and tell us exactly what error or problem you have, where you have it, and maybe you could also remove some unnecessary (and duplicate) sentences.

Comment: PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),fragments);

In this line i am finding out the error..

Comment: @PrabhaKaran what is that error. U can see a red line or X mark mouse hover on it. It'll show the error and post that

Comment: Red line @Raghavendra.. I have already posted in the comment where it was showing the error..

Comment: And also red line occur in the following code 

pager.getCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

Comment: @PrabhaKaran I think u cannot instantiate PagerAdapter its an abstract class

Comment: Then how can i solve this

Comment: @PrabhaKaran u need to create your own custom pager adapter and use it. For reference read [Using ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html#viewpager)

Comment: I am just a beginner i can't understand it.How can I create the custom adapter @ Raghavendra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Solution code:

fragment_bid.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context="com.BoardiesITSolution.CritiMonApp.AppsActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <include layout="@layout/toolbar" />
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill" />
 </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

 <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <!--app:layout_behaviour="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behaviour" />-->
 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

BidFragment.class:

```
public class BidFragment extends Fragment {
  @InjectView(R.id.tabs)
  TabLayout tabs;
  @InjectView(R.id.viewpager)
  ViewPager viewpager;
  SupportMapFragment fragment;
  @Override
  public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);

}


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_bid_booking, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    fragment = (SupportMapFragment) fm.findFragmentById(R.id.map_container);
}
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    ButterKnife.inject(this, view);
    tabs.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("BID"));
    tabs.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("BOOK"));
    tabs.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
    final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter
            (getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), tabs.getTabCount());
    viewpager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewpager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewpager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            onFragmentInteractionListener.OnConfirmrRidesBookingCallBack();
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
}


}
```

PagerAdapter.class:

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
int mNumOfTabs;

public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
    super(fm);
    this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            BidMainFragment bidMainFragment = new BidMainFragment();
            return bidMainFragment;
        case 1:
            BookMainFragment bookMainFragment = new BookMainFragment();
            return bookMainFragment;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mNumOfTabs;
}
}
```

Comment: Apart from only code explain a bit about the fix in your answer.